# Cannot see table view in scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a table view to my scroll view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red

        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        scrollView.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 2000)
    }


}
```

However it doesn't show. It only shows the scrollview background color. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: UITableView inherits from UIScrollView.  You are adding a ScrollView in a ScrollView. That is expected. Why are you adding TableView in ScrollView?

Comment: It being a scroll view is not the issue. If I change it to a UIView it still doesn't work

Comment: Based on your code, there's no reason to do what you're doing (unless if you're just curious how it would turn out). You can add a table-view to a scroll-view, but you've superimposed the table-view entirely over the scroll-view which makes the scroll-view useless. And you should be adding subviews in `loadView` if you're going about this programmatically, not `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that all of the code in your test?  You've not set the datasource and delegate of the tableview, and haven't returned any cells so it's not going to show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the constraint for tableView in NSLayoutConstraint.

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
```

You use view.bottomAnchor or anyothers instead of scrollView, such as:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
```

This will display your tableView. Now you can try to fight with other problems caused by put tableView inside scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use Scrollview under Tableview**, it will make scrollview **useless**. Tableview has inbuilt scrollview(kind of) as you fill up the tables, if the tables row is many and go beyond your screen then scrollview in tableview is automatically enabled. So,Use only tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Add `heightAnchor` constraint to your table view to fix this issue. For example:

```
tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 4 * 80)
```

This example add height anchor to the table view (4 is number of rows, 80 is height of a row)